# Port Forwarding on Internet Shared Connection

Tags: router, openwrt

My computer (A) is connected via WiFi to a home router using OpenWRT (B), which I don't have access.

I share my internet to a Raspberry (C) using Shared Connection from the Network Manager option. So,

```
WAN -> router (B) -> 192.168.1.60/24 (A) -> 10.42.0.93/24 (C)
```

My question is: how can I reach C from the router? i.e. Let's suppose I open port 80 on C, how can I expose that port on WAN?

Comment: You can't without access to router (B) because you need to setup port forwarding in router (B).

Comment: yes, but port forwarding can be from a port on WAN to a port on A, but not on a port on C

Comment: But you said "I don't have access." How are you going to add the port forwarding?

Comment: C is connected to my computer (A) via Shared Connection option, so it cannot see the router (B) to make a port forwarding..

Comment: I mean, my computer (A) is in the same LAN as the router (192.168.1.1/24), but C is in a local network inside my computer (10.42.0.1/24)

Comment: <sigh> Add port forwarding from B to A on the router. Add port forwarding from A to C on the ICS connection. Read about "double NAT"